# Jquery-HTML5 drawing canvas on windows touch screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am creating an application that allows users to draw on the screen using the HTML5 Canvas tag.

This works great when using a mouse, and I even got it working on android using jquery `touch`.

The problem comes when using a windows 7 or 8 tablet. The reason for why it wont work is simple, the browser tries to scroll instead of mousedown and drag.

The reason why it works on android and not windows is due to the fact that android supports `ontouchstart` and `ontouchend` while I can't get it to work on windows tablets.

So, is there any way to get the browser to stop trying to scroll and draw on the screen?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to return false from your event handler?

Comment: Yes, and there were no changes

Comment: Compatibility issues in IE? Unheard of!

Comment: Yeah i know haha, but it is in all browsers not just ie :(

Comment: why don't you just make the page the canvas is on unscrollable?

Comment: can you show us what you have so far?